# Python: Converting a list into a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
['100 ug/ml', '50 ug/ml', '25 ug/ml', '12.5 ug/ml', '6.25 ug/ml', '3.125 ug/ml', 
 '1.5625 ug/ml', '0 ug/ml']
```

and I want to make it into a dictionary where these numbers are keys with empty values:

```
growth_data = {'100 ug/ml': '', '50 ug/ml': '', '25 ug/ml': '', etc...}
```

Comment: why? what do you plan on populating the dict with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the `dict.fromkeys()` method. The first parameter is the list (or iterable) that you want to use as the keys in your dictionary; the second (optional) one is the value for each key. If you give no second argument, `None` will be the value of each key. Be careful with using a mutable object (like `[]`) as your default value, as it will be the same instance shared among all the keys.

```
l = ['100 ug/ml', '50 ug/ml', '25 ug/ml', '12.5 ug/ml', '6.25 ug/ml',
     '3.125 ug/ml', '1.5625 ug/ml', '0 ug/ml']

growth_data = dict.fromkeys(l, '')
```

Comment: @ttdinh if Gabe's answer helped you, you should mark it accepted - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 5):

Assuming x is your list, do `dict((a, '') for a in x)`.